# How to disable the energy of a USB C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, usb

i am doing a program that one feature is disable the USB energy, but I thought that disabling the USB port as we can do in the device manager, the energy stop, I was never so wrong. Can you help me teaching me how to do this in C# if is possible?.

the program that I am doing have to give energy to a circuit, for example a bulb, so in the program I type the day and the hour that I want to turn on the bulb, that is how it works, but I need that the program automatically turn on the bulb and I think is possible disabling the energy of the USB.

Sorry if I have some mistakes writing, I speak Spanish but the community in Spanish isn't too big that the English.